# Parameter Lost Value When Post Action in Same Controller Asp.net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I would like to just post on Mvc Action result which is in controller name **Home** from an Action result in same controller,the Post request send successfully but the parameters lost passing value.

**Calling Post From Controller Home**

```
   [ValidateInput(false)]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult addToWishList(string customcode, string addcusimgSVG, string pagestatus = "", string userinformation="")
    {

        string URI = "http://localhost:49389/services";
        string myParameters = "serviceAndVisitorModel=" + ServiceAndVisitroData;

        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
        }
     //return some view here

    }
```

**Action Result Called by addToWishList present in same Controller**

```
  [Route("services")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult services(AllserviceWebApi serviceAndVisitorModel, string pagename = "service")//string selectedService,string userId,string DealInfo
    {

     //serviceAndVisitorModel is null here

    }
```

**Model**

```
public class AllserviceWebApi
{
    public string packageTypeID { get; set; }
    public string packageTypeCode { get; set; }
    public string pageUrl { get; set; }
    public string pageName { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<pakageInfoList> packageInfoList { get; set; }
    //------visitor object
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public string deviceName { get; set; }
    public string OSName { get; set; }
    public string browserName { get; set; }
    public string countryName { get; set; }

    public string selectedService{ get; set; }
    public string userId{ get; set; }
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public string DealInfo { get; set; }
    public long wishlishid { get; set; }
    public string customlogoCode { get; set; }
    public string customLogoImgSvg { get; set; }
    public bool IsCustomllogo { get; set; }
}
```

**Model Initializing**

```
 AllserviceWebApi ServiceAndVisitroData = new AllserviceWebApi()
            {
                selectedService = serviceids,
                userId = "0",
                OrderId = "0",
                DealInfo = "",
                IPAddress = ipaddress,
                // deviceName: userDevicedata[0],
                OSName = osandversion,
                browserName = browsermajorversion,
                wishlishid = wishid,
                customlogoCode = logocode,
                customLogoImgSvg = logosvg,
                IsCustomllogo = true

            };
```

Please tell me whats wrong with this code.

Comment: Have you tried model ???

Comment: What is `ServiceAndVisitroData`? (the `AllserviceWebApi serviceAndVisitorModel` parameters suggests you want to bind to a complex object - you cannot bind a `string` to complex object)

Comment: @StephenMuecke please suggest me how to bind this?

Comment: I cant guess what `AllserviceWebApi` is or what the value of `ServiceAndVisitroData` is

Comment: @StephenMuecke please consider the question now I have edited

Comment: That is not a model (you have not shown what the property types are). But try `string myParameters = "userId=1&OrderId=2"` to bind those 2 properties

Comment: Check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request

Answer (score 1):

Try to send it via JSON

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;


    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
                string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ServiceAndVisitroData));
            }
```

PS your need to install Newtonsoft.Json via nuget